# Appending strings in the right order

Tags: javascript, string

I have a hash table that contains values under two main keys: `Subject` and `Query`. Each `Query` can have multiple `Subject`.

For example

```
Query-blabla, Subject1-12, Subject2=13
```

I'm trying to build a string that contains each `Query` his own subjects, and it needs to be seperated by a comma `,` so I can insert it into a cvs file, by coulmns.

Everything works great, the only problem I have is with the bold line.

Now it looks something like this:

```
subject,subject,query,subject,,subject,subject,query,subject,,subject...
```

It needs to be:

```
subject, subject, query
subject,subject, query etc...
```

I have the following code

```
for (var k = 0; k < keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray.length; k++)
{

    var isGroupContained = keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].hasItem(currentKey);

    if (isGroupContained)
    {
        //Not relevent: Watch the data structures: sumElements += keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].getItem(currentKey).length;
        sumElements += 1; 

        linescontentSubject = keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].items[currentKey][0].Subject;
        linescontentQuery = keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].items[currentKey][0].Query;

        databegin = linescontentQuery + "," + linescontentSubject;

        if(dataAll.includes(linescontentQuery))
        {
            dataAll = linescontentSubject + "," + dataAll + ",";
        } //this is the problem//
        else 
        {
            dataAll = dataAll + databegin + "\r";
        }

        index += Math.pow(2, k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include at least a sample of the hash table?

Comment: I think that you need explain this a little better, It will helpful if you put an example of input and an example of output

Comment: I think your problem is you only concatenate `'\r'` at the end of line, but you have to concatenate `'\r\n'`.

Comment: I think your problem is you only concatenate '\r' at the end of line, but you have to concatenate '\r\n'

thank you, it works!

Comment: @Daniel You changed the question by quoting the example instead of using a pre-formatted text block. Quoting is for quotes, not for pre-formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to **trim the trailing comma** before you finish the line.

```
else {
    dataAll = dataAll.substring(0, dataAll.length - 2);
    dataAll = dataAll + databegin + "\r";
}
```

An alternative, one that's more concise, is to **use an array** in place of the string concatenation and finish using the array's **join** method.

```
var dataLine = [];

for (var k = 0; k < keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray.length; k++){
    var isGroupContained = keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].hasItem(currentKey);

    if (isGroupContained){
        //Not relevent: Watch the data structures: sumElements += keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].getItem(currentKey).length;
        sumElements += 1; 

        linescontentSubject = keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].items[currentKey][0].Subject;
        linescontentQuery = keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].items[currentKey][0].Query;

        databegin = linescontentQuery + "," + linescontentSubject;

        if(dataLine.includes(linescontentQuery)){
            dataLine.splice(0, linescontentSubject); 
        }
        else {
            dataAll = dataLine.join(',') + databegin + "\r";
            dataLine = []; //reset the dataline
        }

        index += Math.pow(2, k);
    }
}
```